# What does the 「おかけしやして」mean?

Tags: words

Here is the dialogue including the word.

A: とまあこんなところが矢{や}吹{ぶき}丈{じょう}の罪{ざい}状{じょう}だが...

あんたもずいぶんたいへんな少年を保護していたものだな　ええ？

B: どうもごめいわく**おかけしやして**...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> どうもごめいわくおかけし**や**して・・・
>   = どうもご[迷惑]{めいわく}(を)おかけし**ま**して・・・

～しやして(しやす) means ～しまして(します) in regional (probably Edo / 江戸っ子言葉) accent. おか(掛)けします/おかけしました is the humble form of かけます/かけました. 「申し訳ありません(でした)」 or 「すみません(でした)」 is being left out after the おかけしやして・・・.

> どうもご迷惑をおかけしまして、(すみませんでした。)
>   (I am sorry that) I (or, in this context, "he" = 矢吹丈) caused trouble / bothered you...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you must mean

> B: どうもごめいわくおかけし**ゃ**して...

This expression comes from　”～てしまっています。”, in colloquial form.

When used in polite form:

> ご迷惑を**おかけしてしまって**、申し訳ございません。

This is basically in inflection from おかけします。

In this case

> B: どうもごめいわくおかけし**ゃ**して...

It's a conversational shortcut.

Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: 「おかけしやして」の方が「おかけしゃして」よりもまだ一般的だと思います。